# entering ring 0 from user mode

Tags: cpu-architecture

Most modern operating systems run in the protected mode. Now is it possible for the user programs to enter the "ring 0" by directly setting the corresponding bits in some control registers. Or does it have to go through some syscall.

I believe to access the hardware we need to go through the operating system. But if we know the address of the hardware device can we just write some assembly language code with reference to the location of the device and access it. What happens when we give the address of some hardware device in the assembly language code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To enter Ring 0, you must perform a system call, and by its nature, the system controls where you go, because for the call you simply give an index to the CPU, and the CPU looks inside a table to know what to call. You can't really get around the security aspect (obviously) to do something else, but maybe [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/MinimalisticRingZero.aspx) will help.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I read the page where the author writes "We read Global Descriptor Table and write back address of our function on first free spot + desired ring level." I did not get if he intends to say we write to the GDT or some where else. Can we write to the GDT from user mode (ring 3).

Comment: Also I could not find where the code enters ring 0. I could find the transition from ring-0 to ring-3. but not the other way round. Does the code start in ring 0 directly or does it enter ring 0 at some point, if so can you point me where in the code do we enter ring 0. -- Thanks

Comment: Sorry found it. As far as I could tell code is making a call to a function which can run in ring 0 (using callGates). Is it correct... correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks

Comment: Honestly, I tried it a long time ago and it didn't work for me either (it caused a BSOD); I still can't figure out exactly what it does, since he seems to write to the GDT but he shouldn't be able to. I thought maybe you could make sense of it, since I couldn't. :\

Answer (score 2):

You can ask the operating system to map the memory of the hardware device into the memory space of your program. Once that's done, you can just read and write that memory from ring 3. Whether that's possible to do, or how to do that, depends on the operating system or the device.

Answer (score 2):

```
; set PE bit
mov cr0, eax
or eax, 1
mov eax, cr0
; far jump (cs = selector of code segment)
jmp cs:@pm

@pm:
; Now we are in PM
```

Taken from Wikipedia.

Basic idea is to set (to 1) **0th** bit in **cr0** control register.

But if you are already in protected mode (i.e. you are in windows/linux), security restricts you to do it (you are in ring 3 - lowest trust).

So be the first one to get into protected mode.